# JAVASCRIPT - How create empty Object

Tags: javascript, object

**Why this doesn´t work?**

```js
var waypoints_legs = [{leg,latlgn:{lat,lgn}}];
```

Comment: the error message is meaningful: you probably run it in a "strict" context, where the variables must be defined.

Comment: you can create empty object like this var waypoints_legs={};

Comment: You mean `var leg="",lat=0,lgn=0;
var waypoints_legs = [{
  "leg": leg,
  "latlgn": {
    "lat": lat,
    "lgn": lgn
  }
}];` or what?

Comment: its solve, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you defined leg, lat and lgn ? Are you using this script in environment with EcmaScript6 (ES2015) or newer version of JavaScript ? If not, this script doesn't work.

EcmaScript6 and newer :

```
var leg = "leg", lat = "lat", lgn = "lgn"
var waypoints_legs = [{leg,latlgn:{lat,lgn}}]
```

EcmaScript5 and older :

```
'use strict';
var leg = "leg", lat = "lat", lgn = "lgn";
var waypoints_legs = [{"leg":leg,"latlgn":{"lat":lat,"lgn":lgn}}];
```